# Derivative of $4x^5 \tan(\frac{-1}{x})$

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives

I can't seem to be able to get the correct signs for this derivative.
$\frac{d}{dx}(4x^5\tan(\frac{-1}{x}))$

Here's my work:

$= (4x^5)'\tan(\frac{-1}{x}) + 4x^5(\tan(\frac{-1}{x}))'$

$= 20x^4\tan(\frac{-1}{x}) + 4x^5(\tan(\frac{-1}{x}))'$

$= 20x^4\tan(\frac{-1}{x}) + 4x^5(\frac{-1}{x})'\sec^2(\frac{-1}{x})$

$= 20x^4\tan(\frac{-1}{x}) + 4x^5(\frac{-1}{x})'\sec^2(\frac{-1}{x})$

And here is where I think I make my mistake:

$(\frac{-1}{x})' = (-1x^{-1})'$

$(\frac{-1}{x})' = (1x^{-2})$

$(\frac{-1}{x})' = \frac{1}{x^2}$

So plugging that derivative back into the step I left off on in the last equation:

$= 20x^4tan(\frac{-1}{x}) + 4x^5\frac{1}{x^2}sec^2(\frac{-1}{x})$

$= 20x^4tan(\frac{-1}{x}) + 4x^3sec^2(\frac{-1}{x})$

However the answer key and wolfram alpha display the answer to be

$= 20x^4\tan(\frac{-1}{x}) - 4x^3\sec^2(\frac{-1}{x})$

I can't figure out the step where I went wrong... Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint $sec(-\theta)=sec(\theta)$ thats the only mistake.

Comment: Is it not possible for me to keep it as sec(-1/x)? 
EDIT: What line should I apply that rule?

Comment: Its same as $cos(-\theta)=cos(\theta)$ its trigonometric basic rule so the answer is given as per that on wolfram and your book i suppose

Comment: further to this answer note the following output [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+5x%5E4tan(-1%2Fx)) Even Wolfram removes the minus sign.

Answer (score 0):

Wolfram Alpha is using odd-even angle identities to turn $+\sec^2(-1/x)$ into $-sec^2(1/x)$ (and appears to do the same thing to the tangent function when I plug thd equation into Wolfram Alpha myself).  This isn't really necessary,  and so your answer is correct; doing so just removes a $-$ sign,  making the expression a little shorter. If this is for a test you might need to look up the odd-even identities for $\sec x$ and $\tan x$,  otherwise your answer should be fine